# OPC client not reading milliseconds from Honeywell HWHsc.OPCServer

Tags: c#, opc

All,

I have written an OPC client in c# using Interop.OPCAutomation.dll and OPCDAAuto.dll. Data transfer is asynchronous ("by exception").

When I test the OPC client against Matrikon's simulation OPC server, the timestamps of values I am reading have non-zero milliseconds.

When I try reading values from Honeywell Experion's HWHsc.OPCServer, the millisecond part of the timestamps of all values is zero. Is it supposed to be like that or am I missing something ? The Events screen in Experion clearly shows non-zero milliseconds for the digital tags I'm trying to read.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

siim

Comment: Maybe Honeywell Experion's HWHsc. OPCServer does not support millisecond timestamp precision ?

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be like that.

Time resolution is OPC Server specific and depends only on its implementation. In your case time resolution of *HWHsc.OPCServer* is 1 second. And *Matrikon Simulation OPC Server* provides 1 millisecond resolution for timestamps.

Even if DCS supports milliseconds in timestamps (what you see in *Experion*) OPC Server is allowed to round timestamp to seconds or whatever it wants. *OPC Specification* doesn't specify the exact time precision for Servers.

Think about any OPC Server as a set of rules how to convert DCS 'values' to OPC format. In your case the rule for timestamps is to throw away milliseconds.

I recommend you to check *HWHsc.OPCServer* documentation. It is possible that time resolution can be configured.